# Google Analytics for bookmarklets

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, bookmarklet, google-analytics-api

I made a bookmarklet and I would like to use Google Analytics to track it's usage. How would I do that? I found an old post by Remy Sharp that does what I would like but I'm unsure if its outdated. http://remysharp.com/2009/02/27/analytics-for-bookmarklets-injected-scripts/

Comment: The only idea that I have is to inject an iframe of my site. But then I wouldn't get the page that the user is on.

Comment: You can probably pass the current url as a parameter for the iframe url ... make it like `<iframe src="http://mysite.com/trackGA.html?url=CURRENT_PAGE_URL"></iframe>` then you might filter for this in Analytics admin page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to update the script to point to GA's latest request URL format, but the principle is still okay.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I have no idea what the proper url would be (or where to find it), so instead I did it a different way (see my answer).

Comment: basically look in a sniffer like firebug's net tab or httpwatch and look at the request URL being sent to GA from the normal code.

Comment: oooohhhh, thanks, let me try that (totally didn't think of it)

Comment: Using the latest request url works great (added bonus: don't have to load ga.js)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following

```
(function() {
 //loading ga.js - not greatest idea, but can't rely on page having ga.js already
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

 //made a "cool_name" to be able to sort in GA and added domain URL/URI      
    var url = "/cool_name/" + location.host + location.pathname;

 //used "anotherGA" as a 'namespace' to not screw up the real GA for that domain
    _gaq.push(['anotherGA._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX']);
    _gaq.push(['anotherGA._setDomainName']);//not sure if i need this
    _gaq.push(['anotherGA._trackPageview', url]);
})();
```

see: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq (towards the bottom of the page)

To be honest, I don't know if this is an anti-pattern and a misuse of the API, but it seems to work.

Comment: IMO doing it this way is okay.  re: `_setDomainName`.  This is for if you want to track visitor activity across subdomains of a site.  For instance if a visitor goes from sub1.site.com to sub2.site.com normally GA will treat this as two different visit(or)s, because by default GA sets their tracking cookie's domain to be the full domain  (e.g. sub1.site.com) instead of the root domain (site.com).  So you can use this to make sure to catch all subdomains of a site.

Comment: And if you want to be able to track a visitor across multiple domains (e.g. site1.com vs. site2.com) you will also need to use `_setAllowLinker` and add some code to be executed whenever a link to another domain is executed (see this page for details https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite )

Comment: you're saying I would pass the url to `_setDomainName` instead of `_trackPageView`?

Comment: No, you still need `_trackPageview` (or alternatively `_trackEvent`) because that is the "trigger" that makes GA actually make the request.  You would just use `_setDomainName` as a setting to make sure the GA cookie is set at the root domain instead of full domain, and `_setAllowLinker` and additional code from the link I provided, to make sure the cookie info is carried over to the new domain if a visitor goes to a whole different site

Comment: basically if you just want to answer the really basic question of "how many times was my bookmarklet script invoked?" then you don't really need to worry about that extra stuff.  But if you are wanting to look at other metrics like visits and visitors, stuff that involves keeping track of the user instead of treating them as a new person every time the bookmarklet is invoked, then you need to worry about that extra stuff.

Comment: aha, thanks so much for the explanation. (I wanted to grab the url of the page it was used on as well.)